# Facebook Graph API Mailing Address

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The Facebook Graph API seems to be missing a very basic, key piece of documentation.  They don't explain how to obtain the "id" of an object.  Without an id it seems one cannot use any of the features.

For example:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/mailing-address/

GET /v2.8/{mailing-address-id} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

That's pretty simple if you know what to put in place of the variable {mailing-address-id}.

Unfortunately, it doesn't say how to find it (I read the entire guide and Googled for a long time). None of the other methods explain how to obtain an object id either.  Has anyone out there used this and can explain where an id comes from?

Comment: Perhaps you actually want this? `/me?fields=location` (provide the page access token as well, of course). You may also be able to do something like `/<FB Page ID>?fields=location`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

The `contact_address` field may be what you want.

Comment: If by chance there is some easier way to find these IDs than hunting through every method one by one can you please add that to the answer?  Thanks!